# Calculate Function Call To Imported Function In Dumpbin Output

Tags: disassembly

What is the easiest way to determine the function called in dumpbin output. No PDBs available.

The disassembly:

```
  004028E2: 8B 1D 70 42 40 00  mov         ebx,dword ptr ds:[00404270h]
  004028E8: 55                 push        ebp
  004028E9: 56                 push        esi
  004028EA: 57                 push        edi
  004028EB: 8B 7C 24 18        mov         edi,dword ptr [esp+18h]
  004028EF: 89 4C 24 10        mov         dword ptr [esp+10h],ecx
  004028F3: 57                 push        edi
  004028F4: 33 F6              xor         esi,esi
  004028F6: FF D3              call        ebx
```

In this case I know the function is "wcslen" but want to see if there is a good way to resolve this when working in environments where I only have access to Microsoft Visual Studio and not my usual reverse engineering tools.
Dumpbin /imports shows

```
MSVCRT.dll
                40422C Import Address Table
                404C14 Import Name Table
                     0 time date stamp
                     0 Index of first forwarder reference

                   D3 _exit
                   48 _XcptFilter
                  249 exit
                  1E7 _wcmdln
                   8B __wgetmainargs
                  10F _initterm
                   83 __setusermatherr
                   9D _adjust_fdiv
                   6A __p__commode
                   6F __p__fmode
                   81 __set_app_type
                   CA _except_handler3
                   55 __dllonexit
                  186 _onexit
                    E ??1type_info@@UAE@XZ
                   B7 _controlfp
                  2E9 wcsncpy
                  2E6 wcslen
                  2E1 wcscmp
                  2D6 towupper
                   62 __p___argc
                   66 __p___wargv
                  1EA _wcsicmp
                   49 __CxxFrameHandler
                  2C0 strncmp
                  2C1 strncpy
                  2EB wcsrchr
                  2DF wcscat
                  2CB swprintf
```

Dumpbin /raw shows the following at the address **404270h**

```
00404270: 76 4D 00 00 6C 4D 00 00 60 4D 00 00 52 4D 00 00  vM..lM..`M..RM..
```

0x4D76 corresponds to wcslen in CFF Explorer -> Import Directory -> MSVCRT.dll -> wcslen OFTs and FTs (IAT) columns with a hint of "2E6"

This is here, but trying to calculate the offset for the wcslen from these addresses.

```
SECTION HEADER #2
  .rdata name
    102A virtual size
    4000 virtual address (00404000 to 00405029)
    2000 size of raw data
    4000 file pointer to raw data (00004000 to 00005FFF)
       0 file pointer to relocation table
       0 file pointer to line numbers
       0 number of relocations
       0 number of line numbers
40000040 flags
         Initialized Data
         Read Only

RAW DATA #2
  00404000: 82 4E 00 00 A2 4E 00 00 B0 4E 00 00 C0 4E 00 00  .N..¢N..°N..ÀN..
  00404010: D6 4E 00 00 EA 4E 00 00 F8 4E 00 00 08 4F 00 00  ÖN..êN..øN...O..
  00404020: 16 4F 00 00 24 4F 00 00 3A 4F 00 00 4E 4F 00 00  .O..$O..:O..NO..
  00404030: 90 4E 00 00 00 00 00 00 B0 14 00 80 B2 14 00 80  .N......°...²...
  00404040: 9D 0A 00 80 EA 0F 00 80 54 12 00 80 B7 14 00 80  ....ê...T...·...
  00404050: A5 14 00 80 4E 16 00 80 A1 0B 00 80 46 0C 00 80  ¥...N...¡...F...
  00404060: B6 0C 00 80 6B 11 00 80 3B 0C 00 80 B9 0C 00 80  ¶...k...;...¹...
  00404070: A4 0B 00 80 04 0C 00 80 9B 0B 00 80 F1 0E 00 80  ¤...........ñ...
  00404080: F2 0E 00 80 EC 0E 00 80 02 0C 00 80 EB 0F 00 80  ò...ì.......ë...
  00404090: 08 12 00 80 42 11 00 80 95 0E 00 80 31 02 00 80  ....B.......1...
  004040A0: 39 03 00 80 2F 03 00 80 81 02 00 80 90 02 00 80  9.../...........
  004040B0: 68 02 00 80 20 03 00 80 CA 09 00 80 35 0A 00 80  h... ...Ê...5...
  004040C0: 6B 04 00 80 AC 04 00 80 DC 04 00 80 8D 14 00 80  k...¬...Ü.......
  004040D0: 12 11 00 80 EF 12 00 80 80 13 00 80 A0 17 00 80  ....ï...........
  004040E0: E7 06 00 80 9C 14 00 80 43 11 00 80 08 0E 00 80  ç.......C.......
  004040F0: 31 11 00 80 15 0E 00 80 63 09 00 80 DF 07 00 80  1.......c...ß...
  00404100: 75 10 00 80 0A 0A 00 80 A3 17 00 80 E9 0F 00 80  u.......£...é...
  00404110: E8 06 00 80 0D 0D 00 80 75 14 00 80 49 09 00 80  è.......u...I...
  00404120: 25 14 00 80 E2 18 00 80 FB 10 00 80 A6 14 00 80  %...â...û...¦...
  00404130: D1 0E 00 80 DF 12 00 80 53 11 00 80 50 0A 00 80  Ñ...ß...S...P...
  00404140: FF 07 00 80 E4 18 00 80 A0 0E 00 80 C3 13 00 80  ÿ...ä.......Ã...
  00404150: B8 06 00 80 89 14 00 80 86 09 00 80 44 08 00 80  ¸...........D...
  00404160: 99 14 00 80 45 0D 00 80 0D 12 00 80 21 06 00 80  ....E.......!...
  00404170: 77 04 00 80 8D 04 00 80 FA 0A 00 80 5D 03 00 80  w.......ú...]...
  00404180: 1C 02 00 80 37 02 00 80 44 01 00 80 F3 08 00 80  ....7...D...ó...
  00404190: 3A 09 00 80 F6 08 00 80 85 10 00 80 BA 18 00 80  :...ö.......º...
  004041A0: 33 18 00 80 5A 03 00 80 1C 10 00 80 19 02 00 80  3...Z...........
  004041B0: AC 03 00 80 43 18 00 80 1A 02 00 80 60 12 00 80  ¬...C.......`...
  004041C0: 43 09 00 80 F3 02 00 80 D6 01 00 80 1F 0F 00 80  C...ó...Ö.......
  004041D0: 17 02 00 80 99 02 00 80 B3 07 00 80 ED 18 00 80  ........³...í...
  004041E0: 61 01 00 80 A6 0D 00 80 CB 09 00 80 63 01 00 80  a...¦...Ë...c...
  004041F0: AD 04 00 80 54 09 00 80 49 14 00 80 41 04 00 80  ­...T...I...A...
  00404200: 4D 0F 00 80 5F 16 00 80 C8 09 00 80 F2 09 00 80  M..._...È...ò...
  00404210: 80 11 00 80 E3 18 00 80 AD 10 00 80 3B 12 00 80  ....ã...­...;...
  00404220: 28 11 00 80 F9 0D 00 80 00 00 00 00 8A 4D 00 00  (...ù........M..
  00404230: 92 4D 00 00 A0 4D 00 00 A8 4D 00 00 B2 4D 00 00  .M...M..¨M..²M..
  00404240: C4 4D 00 00 D0 4D 00 00 E4 4D 00 00 F4 4D 00 00  ÄM..ÐM..äM..ôM..
  00404250: 04 4E 00 00 12 4E 00 00 24 4E 00 00 44 4E 00 00  .N...N..$N..DN..
  00404260: 52 4E 00 00 5C 4E 00 00 74 4E 00 00 80 4D 00 00  RN..\N..tN...M..
  00404270: 76 4D 00 00 6C 4D 00 00 60 4D 00 00 52 4D 00 00  vM..lM..`M..RM..
  00404280: 44 4D 00 00 38 4D 00 00 24 4D 00 00 1A 4D 00 00  DM..8M..$M...M..
  00404290: 10 4D 00 00 06 4D 00 00 FC 4C 00 00 F0 4C 00 00  .M...M..üL..ðL..
  004042A0: 00 00 00 00 C6 4F 00 00 6E 4F 00 00 7A 4F 00 00  ....ÆO..nO..zO..
  004042B0: 8A 4F 00 00 96 4F 00 00 A6 4F 00 00 BA 4F 00 00  .O...O..¦O..ºO..
  004042C0: 0E 50 00 00 D8 4F 00 00 EC 4F 00 00 FE 4F 00 00  .P..ØO..ìO..þO..
  004042D0: 00 00 00 00 C4 4C 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ....ÄL..........
  004042E0: 10 1B 40 00 E8 42 40 00 11 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  ..@.èB@.........
  004042F0: 46 E1 00 00 46 E1 00 00 0C 00 00 00 26 2D 40 00  Fá..Fá......&-@.
  00404300: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
  00404310: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 F8 2D 40 00 50 1B 40 00  ........ø-@.P.@.
  00404320: B0 1D 40 00 A0 1D 40 00 B0 1D 40 00 F2 2D 40 00  °.@...@.°.@.ò-@.
  00404330: EC 2D 40 00 E6 2D 40 00 E0 2D 40 00 DA 2D 40 00  ì-@.æ-@.à-@.Ú-@.
  00404340: D4 2D 40 00 CE 2D 40 00 20 1B 40 00 C8 2D 40 00  Ô-@.Î-@. .@.È-@.
  00404350: C2 2D 40 00 BC 2D 40 00 B6 2D 40 00 B0 2D 40 00  Â-@.¼-@.¶-@.°-@.
  00404360: AA 2D 40 00 A4 2D 40 00 9E 2D 40 00 98 2D 40 00  ª-@.¤-@..-@..-@.
  00404370: C0 1B 40 00 92 2D 40 00 8C 2D 40 00 86 2D 40 00  À.@..-@..-@..-@.
  00404380: 80 2D 40 00 7A 2D 40 00 74 2D 40 00 6E 2D 40 00  .-@.z-@.t-@.n-@.
  00404390: 68 2D 40 00 62 2D 40 00 5C 2D 40 00 56 2D 40 00  h-@.b-@.\-@.V-@.
  004043A0: 50 2D 40 00 4A 2D 40 00 44 2D 40 00 3E 2D 40 00  P-@.J-@.D-@.>-@.
  004043B0: 38 2D 40 00 32 2D 40 00 2C 2D 40 00 00 00 00 00  8-@.2-@.,-@.....
  004043C0: C0 1F 40 00 C8 43 40 00 0F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  À.@.ÈC@.........
  004043D0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0C 00 00 00 00 24 40 00  .............$@.
  004043E0: 37 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  7...............
  004043F0: 23 00 00 00 C0 24 40 00 11 01 00 00 01 00 00 00  #...À$@.........
  00404400: E8 03 00 00 E8 03 00 00 0C 00 00 00 D0 24 40 00  è...è.......Ð$@.
  00404410: 11 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 EB 03 00 00 EB 03 00 00  ........ë...ë...
  00404420: 0C 00 00 00 30 26 40 00 11 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  ....0&@.........
  00404430: EC 03 00 00 EC 03 00 00 0C 00 00 00 60 26 40 00  ì...ì.......`&@.
  00404440: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
  00404450: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 76 2E 40 00 10 1F 40 00  ........v.@...@.
  00404460: B0 1D 40 00 A0 1D 40 00 B0 1D 40 00 70 2E 40 00  °.@...@.°.@.p.@.
  00404470: 30 2F 40 00 E6 2D 40 00 E0 2D 40 00 DA 2D 40 00  0/@.æ-@.à-@.Ú-@.
  00404480: D4 2D 40 00 CE 2D 40 00 D0 1F 40 00 C8 2D 40 00  Ô-@.Î-@.Ð.@.È-@.
  00404490: C2 2D 40 00 BC 2D 40 00 B6 2D 40 00 B0 2D 40 00  Â-@.¼-@.¶-@.°-@.
  004044A0: AA 2D 40 00 A4 2D 40 00 9E 2D 40 00 98 2D 40 00  ª-@.¤-@..-@..-@.
  004044B0: 24 2F 40 00 1E 2F 40 00 18 2F 40 00 12 2F 40 00  $/@../@../@../@.
  004044C0: 0C 2F 40 00 06 2F 40 00 00 2F 40 00 FA 2E 40 00  ./@../@../@.ú.@.
  004044D0: F4 2E 40 00 EE 2E 40 00 E8 2E 40 00 E2 2E 40 00  ô.@.î.@.è.@.â.@.
  004044E0: DC 2E 40 00 30 1F 40 00 70 28 40 00 80 28 40 00  Ü.@.0.@.p(@..(@.
  004044F0: 6A 2E 40 00 D0 2E 40 00 CA 2E 40 00 C4 2E 40 00  j.@.Ð.@.Ê.@.Ä.@.
  00404500: BE 2E 40 00 B8 2E 40 00 7C 2E 40 00 64 2E 40 00  ¾.@.¸.@.|.@.d.@.
  00404510: A6 2E 40 00 5E 2E 40 00 28 2E 40 00 E0 1F 40 00  ¦.@.^.@.(.@.à.@.
  00404520: 58 2E 40 00 52 2E 40 00 4C 2E 40 00 46 2E 40 00  X.@.R.@.L.@.F.@.
  00404530: 36 2F 40 00 90 28 40 00 B0 1D 40 00 A0 1D 40 00  6/@..(@.°.@...@.
  00404540: B0 1D 40 00 F2 2D 40 00 30 2F 40 00 E6 2D 40 00  °.@.ò-@.0/@.æ-@.
  00404550: E0 2D 40 00 DA 2D 40 00 D4 2D 40 00 CE 2D 40 00  à-@.Ú-@.Ô-@.Î-@.
  00404560: 2A 2F 40 00 C8 2D 40 00 C2 2D 40 00 BC 2D 40 00  */@.È-@.Â-@.¼-@.
  00404570: B6 2D 40 00 B0 2D 40 00 AA 2D 40 00 A4 2D 40 00  ¶-@.°-@.ª-@.¤-@.
  00404580: 9E 2D 40 00 98 2D 40 00 24 2F 40 00 1E 2F 40 00  .-@..-@.$/@../@.
  00404590: 18 2F 40 00 12 2F 40 00 0C 2F 40 00 06 2F 40 00  ./@../@../@../@.
  004045A0: 00 2F 40 00 FA 2E 40 00 F4 2E 40 00 EE 2E 40 00  ./@.ú.@.ô.@.î.@.
  004045B0: E8 2E 40 00 E2 2E 40 00 DC 2E 40 00 B0 1D 40 00  è.@.â.@.Ü.@.°.@.
  004045C0: 70 28 40 00 80 28 40 00 D6 2E 40 00 D0 2E 40 00  p(@..(@.Ö.@.Ð.@.
  004045D0: CA 2E 40 00 C4 2E 40 00 BE 2E 40 00 B8 2E 40 00  Ê.@.Ä.@.¾.@.¸.@.
  004045E0: B2 2E 40 00 AC 2E 40 00 A6 2E 40 00 A0 2E 40 00  ².@.¬.@.¦.@...@.
  004045F0: 9A 2E 40 00 94 2E 40 00 8E 2E 40 00 88 2E 40 00  ..@...@...@...@.
  00404600: 82 2E 40 00 B0 28 40 00 B0 1D 40 00 A0 1D 40 00  ..@.°(@.°.@...@.
  00404610: B0 1D 40 00 F2 2D 40 00 30 2F 40 00 E6 2D 40 00  °.@.ò-@.0/@.æ-@.
  00404620: E0 2D 40 00 DA 2D 40 00 D4 2D 40 00 CE 2D 40 00  à-@.Ú-@.Ô-@.Î-@.
  00404630: 2A 2F 40 00 C8 2D 40 00 C2 2D 40 00 BC 2D 40 00  */@.È-@.Â-@.¼-@.
  00404640: B6 2D 40 00 B0 2D 40 00 AA 2D 40 00 A4 2D 40 00  ¶-@.°-@.ª-@.¤-@.
  00404650: 9E 2D 40 00 98 2D 40 00 24 2F 40 00 1E 2F 40 00  .-@..-@.$/@../@.
  00404660: 18 2F 40 00 12 2F 40 00 0C 2F 40 00 06 2F 40 00  ./@../@../@../@.
  00404670: 00 2F 40 00 FA 2E 40 00 F4 2E 40 00 EE 2E 40 00  ./@.ú.@.ô.@.î.@.
  00404680: E8 2E 40 00 E2 2E 40 00 DC 2E 40 00 B0 1D 40 00  è.@.â.@.Ü.@.°.@.
  00404690: 70 28 40 00 80 28 40 00 D6 2E 40 00 D0 2E 40 00  p(@..(@.Ö.@.Ð.@.
  004046A0: CA 2E 40 00 C4 2E 40 00 BE 2E 40 00 B8 2E 40 00  Ê.@.Ä.@.¾.@.¸.@.
  004046B0: 7C 2E 40 00 AC 2E 40 00 A6 2E 40 00 A0 2E 40 00  |.@.¬.@.¦.@...@.
  004046C0: FF FF FF FF 61 31 40 00 75 31 40 00 08 47 40 00  ÿÿÿÿa1@.u1@..G@.
  004046D0: 10 32 40 00 00 00 00 00 90 63 40 00 00 00 00 00  .2@......c@.....
  004046E0: 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ....ÿÿÿÿ........
  004046F0: D8 46 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ØF@.............
  00404700: 01 00 00 00 F0 46 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ....ðF@.........
  00404710: 00 00 00 00 90 63 40 00 F8 46 40 00 00 00 00 00  .....c@.øF@.....
  00404720: 20 05 93 19 08 00 00 00 40 47 40 00 00 00 00 00   .......@G@.....
  00404730: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
  00404740: FF FF FF FF F0 32 40 00 FF FF FF FF FB 32 40 00  ÿÿÿÿð2@.ÿÿÿÿû2@.
  00404750: 01 00 00 00 06 33 40 00 02 00 00 00 11 33 40 00  .....3@......3@.
  00404760: 03 00 00 00 1C 33 40 00 04 00 00 00 27 33 40 00  .....3@.....'3@.
  00404770: 05 00 00 00 32 33 40 00 06 00 00 00 3D 33 40 00  ....23@.....=3@.
  00404780: 20 05 93 19 07 00 00 00 A0 47 40 00 00 00 00 00   ........G@.....
  00404790: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
  004047A0: FF FF FF FF 60 33 40 00 00 00 00 00 68 33 40 00  ÿÿÿÿ`3@.....h3@.
  004047B0: 01 00 00 00 73 33 40 00 02 00 00 00 81 33 40 00  ....s3@......3@.
  004047C0: 03 00 00 00 8F 33 40 00 04 00 00 00 9D 33 40 00  .....3@......3@.
  004047D0: 05 00 00 00 AB 33 40 00 20 05 93 19 08 00 00 00  ....«3@. .......
  004047E0: F8 47 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  øG@.............
  004047F0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF D0 33 40 00  ........ÿÿÿÿÐ3@.
  00404800: 00 00 00 00 D8 33 40 00 01 00 00 00 E3 33 40 00  ....Ø3@.....ã3@.
  00404810: 02 00 00 00 F1 33 40 00 03 00 00 00 FF 33 40 00  ....ñ3@.....ÿ3@.
  00404820: 04 00 00 00 0D 34 40 00 05 00 00 00 1B 34 40 00  .....4@......4@.
  00404830: 06 00 00 00 29 34 40 00 20 05 93 19 08 00 00 00  ....)4@. .......
  00404840: 58 48 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  XH@.............
  00404850: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF 50 34 40 00  ........ÿÿÿÿP4@.
  00404860: 00 00 00 00 5B 34 40 00 FF FF FF FF 66 34 40 00  ....[4@.ÿÿÿÿf4@.
  00404870: 02 00 00 00 71 34 40 00 03 00 00 00 7C 34 40 00  ....q4@.....|4@.
  00404880: 03 00 00 00 87 34 40 00 FF FF FF FF 92 34 40 00  .....4@.ÿÿÿÿ.4@.
  00404890: 06 00 00 00 9D 34 40 00 20 05 93 19 02 00 00 00  .....4@. .......
  004048A0: B8 48 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ¸H@.............
  004048B0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF C0 34 40 00  ........ÿÿÿÿÀ4@.
  004048C0: 00 00 00 00 C8 34 40 00 20 05 93 19 07 00 00 00  ....È4@. .......
  004048D0: E8 48 40 00 01 00 00 00 20 49 40 00 00 00 00 00  èH@..... I@.....
  004048E0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF E0 34 40 00  ........ÿÿÿÿà4@.
  004048F0: 00 00 00 00 EB 34 40 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ....ë4@.........
  00404900: 02 00 00 00 F3 34 40 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ....ó4@.........
  00404910: 04 00 00 00 06 35 40 00 FF FF FF FF FB 34 40 00  .....5@.ÿÿÿÿû4@.
  00404920: 02 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  ................
  00404930: 38 49 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 A0 61 40 00  8I@..........a@.
  00404940: 00 00 00 00 DC 27 40 00 20 05 93 19 01 00 00 00  ....Ü'@. .......
  00404950: 68 49 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  hI@.............
  00404960: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF 20 35 40 00  ........ÿÿÿÿ 5@.
  00404970: BC 4C 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 D6 4C 00 00  ¼L..........ÖL..
  00404980: D4 42 00 00 20 4A 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ÔB.. J..........
  00404990: E4 4C 00 00 38 40 00 00 14 4C 00 00 00 00 00 00  äL..8@...L......
  004049A0: 00 00 00 00 38 4E 00 00 2C 42 00 00 E8 49 00 00  ....8N..,B..èI..
  004049B0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 60 4F 00 00 00 40 00 00  ........`O...@..
  004049C0: 8C 4C 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 1E 50 00 00  .L...........P..
  004049D0: A4 42 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ¤B..............
  004049E0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 82 4E 00 00 A2 4E 00 00  .........N..¢N..
  004049F0: B0 4E 00 00 C0 4E 00 00 D6 4E 00 00 EA 4E 00 00  °N..ÀN..ÖN..êN..
  00404A00: F8 4E 00 00 08 4F 00 00 16 4F 00 00 24 4F 00 00  øN...O...O..$O..
  00404A10: 3A 4F 00 00 4E 4F 00 00 90 4E 00 00 00 00 00 00  :O..NO...N......
  00404A20: B0 14 00 80 B2 14 00 80 9D 0A 00 80 EA 0F 00 80  °...².......ê...
  00404A30: 54 12 00 80 B7 14 00 80 A5 14 00 80 4E 16 00 80  T...·...¥...N...
  00404A40: A1 0B 00 80 46 0C 00 80 B6 0C 00 80 6B 11 00 80  ¡...F...¶...k...
  00404A50: 3B 0C 00 80 B9 0C 00 80 A4 0B 00 80 04 0C 00 80  ;...¹...¤.......
  00404A60: 9B 0B 00 80 F1 0E 00 80 F2 0E 00 80 EC 0E 00 80  ....ñ...ò...ì...
  00404A70: 02 0C 00 80 EB 0F 00 80 08 12 00 80 42 11 00 80  ....ë.......B...
  00404A80: 95 0E 00 80 31 02 00 80 39 03 00 80 2F 03 00 80  ....1...9.../...
  00404A90: 81 02 00 80 90 02 00 80 68 02 00 80 20 03 00 80  ........h... ...
  00404AA0: CA 09 00 80 35 0A 00 80 6B 04 00 80 AC 04 00 80  Ê...5...k...¬...
  00404AB0: DC 04 00 80 8D 14 00 80 12 11 00 80 EF 12 00 80  Ü...........ï...
  00404AC0: 80 13 00 80 A0 17 00 80 E7 06 00 80 9C 14 00 80  ........ç.......
  00404AD0: 43 11 00 80 08 0E 00 80 31 11 00 80 15 0E 00 80  C.......1.......
  00404AE0: 63 09 00 80 DF 07 00 80 75 10 00 80 0A 0A 00 80  c...ß...u.......
  00404AF0: A3 17 00 80 E9 0F 00 80 E8 06 00 80 0D 0D 00 80  £...é...è.......
  00404B00: 75 14 00 80 49 09 00 80 25 14 00 80 E2 18 00 80  u...I...%...â...
  00404B10: FB 10 00 80 A6 14 00 80 D1 0E 00 80 DF 12 00 80  û...¦...Ñ...ß...
  00404B20: 53 11 00 80 50 0A 00 80 FF 07 00 80 E4 18 00 80  S...P...ÿ...ä...
  00404B30: A0 0E 00 80 C3 13 00 80 B8 06 00 80 89 14 00 80  ....Ã...¸.......
  00404B40: 86 09 00 80 44 08 00 80 99 14 00 80 45 0D 00 80  ....D.......E...
  00404B50: 0D 12 00 80 21 06 00 80 77 04 00 80 8D 04 00 80  ....!...w.......
  00404B60: FA 0A 00 80 5D 03 00 80 1C 02 00 80 37 02 00 80  ú...].......7...
  00404B70: 44 01 00 80 F3 08 00 80 3A 09 00 80 F6 08 00 80  D...ó...:...ö...
  00404B80: 85 10 00 80 BA 18 00 80 33 18 00 80 5A 03 00 80  ....º...3...Z...
  00404B90: 1C 10 00 80 19 02 00 80 AC 03 00 80 43 18 00 80  ........¬...C...
  00404BA0: 1A 02 00 80 60 12 00 80 43 09 00 80 F3 02 00 80  ....`...C...ó...
  00404BB0: D6 01 00 80 1F 0F 00 80 17 02 00 80 99 02 00 80  Ö...............
  00404BC0: B3 07 00 80 ED 18 00 80 61 01 00 80 A6 0D 00 80  ³...í...a...¦...
  00404BD0: CB 09 00 80 63 01 00 80 AD 04 00 80 54 09 00 80  Ë...c...­...T...
  00404BE0: 49 14 00 80 41 04 00 80 4D 0F 00 80 5F 16 00 80  I...A...M..._...
  00404BF0: C8 09 00 80 F2 09 00 80 80 11 00 80 E3 18 00 80  È...ò.......ã...
  00404C00: AD 10 00 80 3B 12 00 80 28 11 00 80 F9 0D 00 80  ­...;...(...ù...
  00404C10: 00 00 00 00 8A 4D 00 00 92 4D 00 00 A0 4D 00 00  .....M...M...M..
  00404C20: A8 4D 00 00 B2 4D 00 00 C4 4D 00 00 D0 4D 00 00  ¨M..²M..ÄM..ÐM..
  00404C30: E4 4D 00 00 F4 4D 00 00 04 4E 00 00 12 4E 00 00  äM..ôM...N...N..
  00404C40: 24 4E 00 00 44 4E 00 00 52 4E 00 00 5C 4E 00 00  $N..DN..RN..\N..
  00404C50: 74 4E 00 00 80 4D 00 00 76 4D 00 00 6C 4D 00 00  tN...M..vM..lM..
  00404C60: 60 4D 00 00 52 4D 00 00 44 4D 00 00 38 4D 00 00  `M..RM..DM..8M..
  00404C70: 24 4D 00 00 1A 4D 00 00 10 4D 00 00 06 4D 00 00  $M...M...M...M..
  00404C80: FC 4C 00 00 F0 4C 00 00 00 00 00 00 C6 4F 00 00  üL..ðL......ÆO..
  00404C90: 6E 4F 00 00 7A 4F 00 00 8A 4F 00 00 96 4F 00 00  nO..zO...O...O..
  00404CA0: A6 4F 00 00 BA 4F 00 00 0E 50 00 00 D8 4F 00 00  ¦O..ºO...P..ØO..
  00404CB0: EC 4F 00 00 FE 4F 00 00 00 00 00 00 C4 4C 00 00  ìO..þO......ÄL..
  00404CC0: 00 00 00 00 19 00 47 65 74 41 64 61 70 74 65 72  ......GetAdapter
  00404CD0: 73 49 6E 66 6F 00 69 70 68 6C 70 61 70 69 2E 64  sInfo.iphlpapi.d
  00404CE0: 6C 6C 00 00 4D 46 43 34 32 75 2E 44 4C 4C 00 00  ll..MFC42u.DLL..
  00404CF0: CB 02 73 77 70 72 69 6E 74 66 00 00 DF 02 77 63  Ë.swprintf..ß.wc
  00404D00: 73 63 61 74 00 00 EB 02 77 63 73 72 63 68 72 00  scat..ë.wcsrchr.
  00404D10: C1 02 73 74 72 6E 63 70 79 00 C0 02 73 74 72 6E  Á.strncpy.À.strn
  00404D20: 63 6D 70 00 49 00 5F 5F 43 78 78 46 72 61 6D 65  cmp.I.__CxxFrame
  00404D30: 48 61 6E 64 6C 65 72 00 EA 01 5F 77 63 73 69 63  Handler.ê._wcsic
  00404D40: 6D 70 00 00 66 00 5F 5F 70 5F 5F 5F 77 61 72 67  mp..f.__p___warg
  00404D50: 76 00 62 00 5F 5F 70 5F 5F 5F 61 72 67 63 00 00  v.b.__p___argc..
  00404D60: D6 02 74 6F 77 75 70 70 65 72 00 00 E1 02 77 63  Ö.towupper..á.wc
  00404D70: 73 63 6D 70 00 00 E6 02 77 63 73 6C 65 6E 00 00  scmp..æ.wcslen..
  00404D80: E9 02 77 63 73 6E 63 70 79 00 D3 00 5F 65 78 69  é.wcsncpy.Ó._exi
  00404D90: 74 00 48 00 5F 58 63 70 74 46 69 6C 74 65 72 00  t.H._XcptFilter.
  00404DA0: 49 02 65 78 69 74 00 00 E7 01 5F 77 63 6D 64 6C  I.exit..ç._wcmdl
  00404DB0: 6E 00 8B 00 5F 5F 77 67 65 74 6D 61 69 6E 61 72  n...__wgetmainar
  00404DC0: 67 73 00 00 0F 01 5F 69 6E 69 74 74 65 72 6D 00  gs...._initterm.
  00404DD0: 83 00 5F 5F 73 65 74 75 73 65 72 6D 61 74 68 65  ..__setusermathe
  00404DE0: 72 72 00 00 9D 00 5F 61 64 6A 75 73 74 5F 66 64  rr...._adjust_fd
  00404DF0: 69 76 00 00 6A 00 5F 5F 70 5F 5F 63 6F 6D 6D 6F  iv..j.__p__commo
  00404E00: 64 65 00 00 6F 00 5F 5F 70 5F 5F 66 6D 6F 64 65  de..o.__p__fmode
  00404E10: 00 00 81 00 5F 5F 73 65 74 5F 61 70 70 5F 74 79  ....__set_app_ty
  00404E20: 70 65 00 00 CA 00 5F 65 78 63 65 70 74 5F 68 61  pe..Ê._except_ha
  00404E30: 6E 64 6C 65 72 33 00 00 4D 53 56 43 52 54 2E 64  ndler3..MSVCRT.d
  00404E40: 6C 6C 00 00 55 00 5F 5F 64 6C 6C 6F 6E 65 78 69  ll..U.__dllonexi
  00404E50: 74 00 86 01 5F 6F 6E 65 78 69 74 00 0E 00 3F 3F  t..._onexit...??
  00404E60: 31 74 79 70 65 5F 69 6E 66 6F 40 40 55 41 45 40  1type_info@@UAE@
  00404E70: 58 5A 00 00 B7 00 5F 63 6F 6E 74 72 6F 6C 66 70  XZ..·._controlfp
  00404E80: 00 00 2E 00 43 6C 6F 73 65 48 61 6E 64 6C 65 00  ....CloseHandle.
  00404E90: 83 00 44 65 76 69 63 65 49 6F 43 6F 6E 74 72 6F  ..DeviceIoContro
  00404EA0: 6C 00 50 00 43 72 65 61 74 65 46 69 6C 65 57 00  l.P.CreateFileW.
  00404EB0: E0 01 47 65 74 56 65 72 73 69 6F 6E 45 78 57 00  à.GetVersionExW.
  00404EC0: 76 01 47 65 74 4D 6F 64 75 6C 65 46 69 6C 65 4E  v.GetModuleFileN
  00404ED0: 61 6D 65 57 00 00 7A 01 47 65 74 4D 6F 64 75 6C  ameW..z.GetModul
  00404EE0: 65 48 61 6E 64 6C 65 57 00 00 F5 01 47 6C 6F 62  eHandleW..õ.Glob
  00404EF0: 61 6C 46 72 65 65 00 00 00 02 47 6C 6F 62 61 6C  alFree....Global
  00404F00: 55 6E 6C 6F 63 6B 00 00 F9 01 47 6C 6F 62 61 6C  Unlock..ù.Global
  00404F10: 4C 6F 63 6B 00 00 EE 01 47 6C 6F 62 61 6C 41 6C  Lock..î.GlobalAl
  00404F20: 6C 6F 63 00 89 03 57 69 64 65 43 68 61 72 54 6F  loc...WideCharTo
  00404F30: 4D 75 6C 74 69 42 79 74 65 00 0F 01 47 65 74 43  MultiByte...GetC
  00404F40: 6F 6D 70 75 74 65 72 4E 61 6D 65 57 00 00 B0 01  omputerNameW..°.
  00404F50: 47 65 74 53 74 61 72 74 75 70 49 6E 66 6F 57 00  GetStartupInfoW.
  00404F60: 4B 45 52 4E 45 4C 33 32 2E 64 6C 6C 00 00 BE 01  KERNEL32.dll..¾.
  00404F70: 4C 6F 61 64 49 63 6F 6E 57 00 3F 02 53 65 6E 64  LoadIconW.?.Send
  00404F80: 4D 65 73 73 61 67 65 57 00 00 B6 00 44 72 61 77  MessageW..¶.Draw
  00404F90: 49 63 6F 6E 00 00 FF 00 47 65 74 43 6C 69 65 6E  Icon..ÿ.GetClien
  00404FA0: 74 52 65 63 74 00 5D 01 47 65 74 53 79 73 74 65  tRect.].GetSyste
  00404FB0: 6D 4D 65 74 72 69 63 73 00 00 A6 01 49 73 49 63  mMetrics..¦.IsIc
  00404FC0: 6F 6E 69 63 00 00 42 00 43 6C 6F 73 65 43 6C 69  onic..B.CloseCli
  00404FD0: 70 62 6F 61 72 64 00 00 49 02 53 65 74 43 6C 69  pboard..I.SetCli
  00404FE0: 70 62 6F 61 72 64 44 61 74 61 00 00 C1 00 45 6D  pboardData..Á.Em
  00404FF0: 70 74 79 43 6C 69 70 62 6F 61 72 64 00 00 F5 01  ptyClipboard..õ.
  00405000: 4F 70 65 6E 43 6C 69 70 62 6F 61 72 64 00 C4 00  OpenClipboard.Ä.
  00405010: 45 6E 61 62 6C 65 57 69 6E 64 6F 77 00 00 55 53  EnableWindow..US
  00405020: 45 52 33 32 2E 64 6C 6C 00 00                    ER32.dll..
```

Comment: Afaik dumpbin will utilize. Pdb and resolve func names try pointing to a symsrv path if possible and  check

Comment: Find the dll load the dll in dumpbin and add rva 4d76 + base and locate the symbol it is. Import table rva which is showm in /raw

Comment: ?@404d76 the string wcslen is available in the dump you added mfc42u.dll